# How to delete particular lines in vim editor

Tags: vim, delete, line

Suppose I have 50 lines in my vim editor and I have to delete particular lines (5,9,16,28) in a single command.

Comment: Where do you keep track of the line numbers to delete?

Answer (score 2):

It's unwieldy to manipulate on separate lines at once, but can be done:

```
:g/\v%5l|%9l|%16l|%28l/d
```

- [`:g/.../`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html?#%3Ag) - Act on lines matching pattern `/.../`.
- `\v` - [very magic](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html?#%2F%5Cv), less escaping for special characters in regular expressions.
- [`%<num>l`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html?#%2F%5C%25l) - match on line number `<num>` (so `%5l|%9l|...` matches the 5th line or the 9th line or ... .
- [`:d`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html?#%3Ad) deletes the lines.

If it's just one line, or a range of lines, you could do `:<num>d` or `:<start>,<end>d` (e.g., `:5d` for the fifth line, or `:9,16d` for the range of lines from 9th to the 16th line (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

```
:5d|9d|16d|28d
```

Is how to put four single commands in a row. But better turn it around:

```
:28d|16d|9d|5d
```

To keep the numbering constant.

---

A more flexible way is to use vimscript. Squeezed on one line this is:

```
:for n in [28,16,9,5] | call deletebufline("%",n,n) | endfor
```